# Java bytecode specification

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Is there a nice place for learning the JVM bytecode instruction set. The specification perhaps and maybe some tutorials?

I ask because I would like to design a toy language and a compiler for it that generates JVM bytecode.

Thanks for your knowledge and perhaps googling.

Answer (score 23):

A good reference for Java bytecode specification is the [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/).

See [Chapter 4. The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) and [Chapter 6. The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html).

Comment: You need to be looking at the JVM specification not the other one

Answer (score 12):

A little more "graphic" explanation, IBM developer works: [Understanding bytecode makes you a better programmer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode).

Comment: [Archive.org link to "Understanding bytecode makes you a better programmer"](https://web.archive.org/web/20080617211727/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/), since the IBM one is gone.

Answer (score 5):

The book [Programming for the Java Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309726) explains the JVM instruction set and how to write code for it. It also introduces a bytecode assembler called Oolong, which I have not been able to download. You can, however, use [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/), the predecessor of Oolong. Essentially, you write a text file with instructions and Jasmin will spit out a .class file. The book was published in 1999, but it is still a good and gentle introduction to the VM.

Comment: Jasmin is unmaintained and lacks support for many classfile features. I'd recommend using the Krakatau Assembler instead, which is backwards compatible with Jasmin but much more powerful. (Disclosure: I wrote it).

Answer (score 4):

Also useful are the [javap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/) disassembler and bytecode manipulation frameworks like [ASM](http://asm.objectweb.org/) and [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/), even if all you want to do is verify your classes.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) is a good place to start.

See Chapter 4 [The class File Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html).  The updates cover new attributes added since the 2nd edition was made.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, I suggest generating Java code from your language.

This will make reading and debugging much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps check out [Preon's example on how to parse a Java class file](https://github.com/preon/preon/blob/master/preon-samples/preon-sample-bytecode/src/main/java/org/codehaus/preon/sample/bytecode/ClassFile.java). It has a fairly complete representation of the bytecode in a Java object model.

Comment: Link's dead: no repository with that name.

Comment: Thanks GKFX, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

A new version of the specification has been released:

[The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html)

This new addition does exclude the chapter on *Java Programming Language Concepts* which folks may or may not find useful. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html) for that chapter in the Second Edition of the spec.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more specialized, but [here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/click-fast-bytecodes-funny-languages) is an on-line presentation on how to optimize generated bytecode for running on the JVM. It was presented at the recent [JVM Languages Summit](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/jvmlangsummit/) conferences. InfoQ has [a collection of presentations](http://www.infoq.com/JVMLanguageSummit) from that conference which might be of help to someone wanting to bring up a language on the JVM (or to see what's already been done).