# Need help on method signature

Tags: java

I have found that call stack helps in finding the line number of a method invoker in source code, but suppose I am working on bytecodes and do not have source code. I need to find some way of finding the caller methods signature. Please suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have the source code, but you're trying to use an object or static method from the class?  Did you get documentation?  (Otherwise, how would you use it?)

Comment: Try looking at this older thread, I think it's similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358121/java-bytecode-specification

Comment: I am working on reverse engineering and the requirement is to extract information without use of source code or any documentation. Can ASM help in some way I need a quick solution to fix this problem that too programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html), e.g.

```
$ ls
ICODecoder.class

$ javap ICODecoder    
public class net.sf.image4j.codec.ico.ICODecoder extends java.lang.Object{
    public static java.util.List read(java.io.File)       throws java.io.IOException;
    public static java.util.List readExt(java.io.File)       throws java.io.IOException;
    public static java.util.List read(java.io.InputStream)       throws java.io.IOException;
    public static java.util.List readExt(java.io.InputStream)       throws java.io.IOException;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new Exception().printStacktrace();
Then use a decompiler